# Q and A application in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am very new to Xcode and am trying to learn as fast as i can.

As i am learning i would like to try and make a simple "question and answer" application for IOS. Like this:

Question: Is the moon bigger than a table?

Answer: "YES" or "NO"

And one of the answers is right the other is wrong. After you chosen your option and gotten a right or wrong answer i would like a new question built in the same way to appear.

So, first of all, is this kind of application even "easy" to make and if so do you know if there is some kind of tutorial that is similar to what i want to do? I've tried to search for hours now but i have not found anything.

If there is no tutorial would one of you want to tell my how to make one?

I know that this is a very big question to ask but it would be great if someone could help me!

Thank you!

Comment: How far have you got with your app? Can you show us some code you've written already? You need to ask specific questions to get answers.

Answer (score 1):

Keep working on the learning. Don't worry too much about producing something useful yet -- you're trying to put the puzzle together before you've seen all the pieces. Break your problem down into much smaller problems:

- How do I display text on the screen?
- How do I change that text?
- How can I put a button on the screen?
- How do I find out when the user taps the button?
- How do I read data from a file?
- How do I write data to a file?

Once you understand the parts, you'll be able to put your Q&A app together pretty easily. If you try to get to the end goal without first learning the basics, you're going to end up frustrated with the process and building the app will take much longer than it would otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use labels to display the question.  YES and NO are two different buttons, that the user can click on. Each button is connected to an IBAction that tells the app which button the user clicked.  The app then checks to see if that response is correct, and notifies the user if it is.  Then, repeat with a different question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are some wonderful resources online for the beginner. Heres just one:

http://maniacdev.com/2011/02/ios-beginner-screencasts-xcode-and-objective-c-from-the-start/

These happen to be screencasts so they are easy to follow.